# Using a screen capture of a remote stack trace without line numbers, how can I correlate this to my source code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, stack-trace, pdb-files

Somebody recently left my company and I inherited their project.  I have all of the source code as well as the environment which created the currently deployed web app.  This is a C# web app done in VS 2017.  One of our customers got a NullReferenceException and I'd like to pinpoint things a bit.  There are PDB files on the server but, unfortunately, the stack traces do not have line numbers.

Obviously, adding numbers to the stack traces is something that I could look at doing in the future.  But for now, do I have what is necessary to correlate the stack trace with my source code such that I can pinpoint the line where things went bad?  If so, how can I do this?

Comment: I had something similar recently, what I ended up doing was putting break points periodically and with trial and error eventually found it.  Unfortunately I don't know the real solution, but the break points allowed me to narrow it down and correct the code, especially if it's reproduceable. I'm watching to see if there is a better solution. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is on a server and the source code is on my workstation, so I can't readily set a break point.  I know that there are tools that would allow me to do something like that but our servers and network are very locked down.